# Connection String Section still not protected after publishing and installing the app

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, connection-string

-I have the Connection Strings defined for System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection

-I never configured the RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider so I guess this is the default provider and the code

```
'Declaration
<PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name := "FullTrust")> _
Public NotInheritable Class RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider _
    Inherits ProtectedConfigurationProvider
```

is not needed

-Instead of using the classic code of
ToggleConfigEncryption
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

I'm using this code when I load the form to encrypt the ConnectionString section:

```
Dim appconfig As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

Dim constringsec As ConnectionStringsSection = appconfig.ConnectionStrings
    constringsec.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider")
```

Taken from https://juan-cuenca.blogspot.com.uy/2015/01/encriptar-archivos-de-configuracion.html

When I run my app from Visual Studio the program works and I can find on my Debug folder the file
myApp.exe.xml **and also the file myApp.vshost.exe.xml** are both with

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
<EncryptedData>
  <CipherData>
    <CipherValue>AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sB....
  </CipherData>
</EncryptedData>
```

So I think the encryption is working fine at Debugging time.

The problem:
-When I publish my app on my web server and then install the app like any Windows app the program still works, but on my C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\

the file myApp.exe.xml is still with plain text on the ConnectionString section.

(And the other file myApp.vshost.exe.xml is not there)

Do I need to do something more on the code or Publish configuration?? (Maybe one "after install" code?)
Or is something about Windows permissions?

**Update info**

Well now It's working but with a extrange behavior. After the installation and execution of the program on another computer I have two folders on AppData\Local\Apps.... one of this folder with the APP.Config encrypted and the other one with no encryption at all. I proved deleting this second file and the application still run fine. **But why this file exist with plain text after running the program?**

Comment: [One option is not to save the connection string at all.  Use the ConnectionStringBuilder to create it at runtime.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41211696/1070452)

Comment: You said yourself that you're executing that code when you open a form.  If you look at the config file before opening the form then obviously that code hasn't been executed so the config file will not have been encrypted.

Comment: @jmcilhinney right, but even after the code is executed still I have text plain on the ConnectionString section.

Comment: I would suggest that that is not the case and you likely haven't tested properly.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Well now It's working but with a extrange behavior. After the installation and execution of the program on another computer I have two folders on AppData\Local\Apps.... one of this folder with the APP.Config encrypted and the other one with no encryption at all. I proved deleting this second file and the application still run fine. But why this file exist with plain text after running the program?